# A problem with initializing textView in fragment

Tags: java, android, view, fragment

When I start activity, I also start the fragment

`conversion_1 = new Conversion();`

There is an OnCreateView in the fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_conversion, container, false);
        curr_to_txt_1 = view.findViewById(R.id.curr_to_txt);
        curr_to_txt_1.setText("rrr");
        return view;
    }
```

When I call `curr_to_txt_1.setText("text");` , it works in OnCreateView but the app is stopping if I call it in a void funcion later (the function is called in activity and the fuction itself works)

```
public void set_curr_to_txt() {
        curr_to_txt_1.setText("rrr");
    }
```

It says that curr_ro_text is null, but it have been initialized

Comment: Use onViewCreated().

Comment: if you call this method from your activity make sure that the onViewCreated on the fragment is been called

Comment: @Eyosiyas



`@Override
    public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        curr_to_txt_1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.curr_to_txt);
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    }`
I did, but still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I tink....

You can use onViewCreated for create the 'curr_to_txt_1' and you not need the view variable.

```
public class Test extends Fragment {


private TextView text;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_layout, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    /*
    * Write your bind here
    * */
    text=view.findViewById(R.id.view_id);
}
```

}

considering the fragment [life cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle), in the onViewCreated, the fragment exist and can bind with components

Any question, I will be happy to help you!

Comment: what you mean as binding with components?
sorry for stupid questions, i'm just a beginner

Comment: No problem :), I'm here to help you, when you call 'findViewById' you say for android bind this element in view in this variable, understand? Sorry for the delay.